# OAuth2 client without access token

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0

So before I start, I'm a bit of an OAuth2 newbie, so still trying to really wrap my head around the various permission scopes and grants.

I've managed to successfully implement an OAuth2 server using the [Laravel OAuth2 Server](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) package.

The current site I'm working on will simply dogfood from the API, using the `client_credentials` grant type. I've managed to get this successfully working and can make API calls with the provided access token.

However, I'm wondering how I can implement an architecture similar to Instagram, Soundcloud, etc, who don't require an `access_token` for basic endpoints, just a `client_id`. How do they do this? Is this a custom grant type?

Preferably, I'd only like to start requiring an access token when accessing private resources, such as those for modifying user information, etc. As far as I'm aware, for these I'd need to use the `password` grant type, which isn't a problem.

Answer (score 5):

OAuth has a few flows such as 2-legged or 3-legged which basically tells the developer how many requests he needs to make to the server to get the resource he wants.

For example, in a 2-legged flow you send a request with your id and secret (*first request*), you get back an access_token and using that token you can make other request for the resource you want (*second request*).

Comming back to your Instagram example, you can think at using just `client_id` as a 1-legged OAuth flow, because you make only one request to server to get the resource you want.

You can use such a flow for less sensitive resources, like a profile photo or user's nickname for example.

The implementation of a 1-legged flow is simple:
 - If the `user_id` is valid and the application doesn't need user approval to access  requested resource, go ahead and show the resource.

So implementing a 1-legged flow consists in checking if the client_id is valid and checking if the requested resource needs user permission. That being said, you can use 1-legged for requesting a user profile photo, but you can't use the same flow for requesting the user's private messages.

You can read more about each OAuth Flow in [The OAuth Bible](https://github.com/Mashape/mashape-oauth/blob/master/FLOWS.md).

Answer (score 2):

You have two different resources on your server - a) Resources that need some access checks b) Resources that are publicly accessible.

Actions on resources that need access checks should require that a user has been identified via the OAuth header in the request. In the context of Laravel - this would be a route with the 'before' key specified as Oauth.

Actions that do not need access could glean context about what user is relevant by building your routes to accept an argument that gives you context about the user. Let's say that you have a profile that a user can see without any sort of access.  Your API endpoint for a JSON representation of that could be /api/profile/[user_id], where [user_id] is the ID of the user profile you would like to see. For these routes where you do not care about access, you can leave off the oauth before filter in your route declaration.

Comment: I understand, but not quite what I'm looking for. Soundcloud, Instagram, etc, do require a `client_id` as security for their basic endpoints, and an `access_token` for secure endpoints. Both are a form of security, the latter being stronger. They haven't just left their basic endpoints open, which is what I'm looking to achieve. This would allow my client application to avoid constantly requesting access tokens, until the user actually logs in. Unfortunately your suggestion would leave the API completely open at basic level.